# Sticky posts or Featured posts only on Homepage

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have made a Featured posts  ( Film en box office ) 
the problem is the featured posts duplicate on all post pages and Taxonomy pages
I want display and SET it only in homepage 
and avoid duplicate in Taxonomy pages .

[image]

this is the code of my sticky posts on home.php

```
<?php $args = array(
        //'orderby' => 'featured-checkbox',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=> 10,
        'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                        'key' => 'featured-checkbox',
                        'value' => 'yes'
                )
            )
     );

$featured_query = new WP_Query($args);?>

<?php if ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>

<?php while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : $featured_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php   if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ...
```

Im also doing a code in Functions to display a featured Checkbox in Add Article

Comment: What is the relationship between your `featured-checkbox` posts and sticky posts?

Comment: if you check the checkbox of featured when u want add article it will display with others sticky posts ! @s_ha_dum